# Exclude Certain Locations in Google Maps Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, google-places-api

How do you stop certain countries from ever showing up in Google Maps Autocomplete?

I've found several solutions for narrowing down the search to certain areas, but am looking for a way to have a global search with only a few locations missing.

**Background:**

I have certain countries that are illegal for me to operate in, say 10~ in the world. We have a text box with google maps autocomplete for global searches, and I never want these countries to show up as options.

I have found ways to restrict the autocomplete to max 5 countries (`componentRestrictions`), but I want 240~ countries to be enabled in the dropdown and just never want to see the 10 countries. The only other answers I've found related to this solution revolved around actually clubbing together autocomplete results from `.pac-containers` with different sets of restrictions (240/5), which would generate a lot of calls for each character.

Other maps `options` I've looked into, like `bounds` and `components`, all revolve around restricting the limits of the search to one space, not excluding certain locations from the global space.

**Code setup:**

Api:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${googlePlacesApiKey}&libraries=places
```

Autocomplete:

```
new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options)
```

Restrictions Example:

```
restrictions = { 'country': ['CU', 'AE', 'AF', 'AG', 'AI'] }
this.autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions(restrictions);
this.options.componentRestrictions = restrictions;
```

(Restrictions on countries maxes out at 5 - to play around with restrictions, [google hosts a nice js fiddle with documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-multiple-countries).)

Answer (score 1):

This worked with the inclusion method (`include` hundreds of countries): like the one developed by Chaussin at 
`https://codepen.io/fchaussin/pen/KgEApw?editors=0010`

This stops certain countries from ever showing up by only ever rendering the countries you want.

Essentially, loop together multiple `service.getPlacePredictions` then figure out a way to display them. This takes a long time (you'll have a ton of over query limit requests because Google limits their api per minute) and is nowhere near practical for any production level service that wants to render the expanded predictions for hundreds of countries, but works for more than 5 easily.

```
countries = [...long string of country codes]

  getAllPredictions(searchText) {
    const service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
    return Promise.all(
      _.chunk(this.countries, 5).map(countries => {
        return this.getPrediction(searchText, countries);
      })
    ).then(predictions => {
      return _.filter(_.flatten(predictions));
    });
  }

  getPrediction(searchText, country) {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
      service.getPlacePredictions({
        input: searchText,
        componentRestrictions: {
          country: country,
        },
        types: ['(cities)']
      }, async (data, status) => {
        if( status === 'OVER_QUERY_LIMIT'){
          resolve( await this.getPrediction(searchText, country) );
        }else{
          resolve(data);
        }
      });
    });
  }
```